# Python: Retrieve elements from a variable nested dictionary

Tags: python, nested

I am using json to load content(json) of a file into a dictionary. Certain elements of this dictionary have a nested dictionary structure. However, this nested dictionary may have certain elements depending on certain criteria. For example: 
tempdict = {'a':{'a':[0,1,2,3], 'b':2}, 'b':{'a':1, 'b':2}}

As you can see in this case tempdict.get('a').get('a')[0] will return a 0 in this case but there will be times where the outer element 'a' will be missing and hence the expression would return TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

I don't know a priori if 'a' will be present or not. So in this scenario is there some form of optional chaining that I can perform? 
Appreciate your time and suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

print tempdict.get('a', {}).get('a', [None])[0]

Comment: Thanks,,that is what I needed